# Preparations to finals, validation needed

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have an exam in a few days from now and I'm very nervous. I tried to tackle this one with all I got, but I'm not sure if I'm correct. If anyone can direct me, and tell me if and where I'm doing something wrong it'll be great!

\begin{cases}
\dot{x} & =2x-5y+3-e^{t}\\
\dot{y} & =x-2y+1-e^{t}
\end{cases}

I have found complex eigenvalues/vectors for the homogeneous part:

$x_H=c_{1}e^{it}\left(\begin{matrix}2+i\\
1
\end{matrix}\right)+c_{2}e^{-it}\left(\begin{matrix}2-i\\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$

To make it real: since the eigenvalues are $\pm i$
 , I know that $ A= \left[ \begin{matrix}2 & -5\\
1 & -2
\end{matrix} \right] $
  is similar to $\left[\begin{matrix}\cos t & \sin t\\
-\sin t & \cos t
\end{matrix}\right] $
  so:
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
e^{At} & =\left[\begin{matrix}2 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cos t & \sin t\\
-\sin t & \cos t
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}2 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\\
 & =\left[\begin{matrix}2\cos t-\sin t & 2\sin t+\cos t\\
\cos t & \sin t
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\
1 & -2
\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}2\sin t+\cos t & -5\sin t\\
\sin t & -2\sin t+\cos t
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{array}
 $$

Now, I need to find the particular solutions using this matrix:
$$ \left[\begin{matrix}2\sin t+\cos t & -5\sin t\\
\sin t & -2\sin t+\cos t
\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} \dot{u_1} \\ \dot{u_2}
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} 3-e^t \\ 1-e^t
\end{matrix}\right] $$
I got:
$$\begin{array}{cl} {u_1} & = (1 + e^t) \cos t + (3 - 2 e^t) \sin t  \\ {u_2} & =  \cos t  + \sin t - e^t \sin t \end{array}$$
Hence the solution is: $ \left(\begin{matrix} {c_1}\cdot(2\sin t + \cos t ) -5{c_2}\sin t + (1 + e^t) \cos t + (3 - 2 e^t) \sin t \\ {c_1}\sin t +{c_2}(\cos t -2 \sin t) + \cos t  + \sin t - e^t \sin t
\end{matrix}\right) $

I have tried to verify by "injecting" the solution I got in the initial equation but each time I tried to verify the solution this way I get different results, none of them implies I'm correct.

Comment: An easy way to check solutions to a system is to plug it in and see that it works.

Comment: I'm only asking because it didn't work. Not with my calculations anyway.

Comment: Ok. You asked "is it OK"...implying you hadn't done this yet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit! Thanks.